# Invoice Due Date and Discount no longer populate automatically in new invoicing view

Tags: xero-api

We have a Xero Certified Integration which submits new invoices via the Xero API. When submitting a new invoice previously the invoice Due Date and Discount would populate automatically from the customer record when using classic invoicing view. This no longer occurs with the introduction of the new invoicing view.

Is there a way we can we restore this behaviour for new invoicing? Or will we need to perform the calculations prior to submitting the invoice - at the risk of inconsistencies with how Xero performs the calculation.

*Example API request*:

POST https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices

```json
{
    "Url": "https://example.org/invoice?ref=db5f8bcf-1813-4b74-984f-0489a587bddc",
    "LineItems": [
        {
            "ItemCode": "GB1-White",
            "Description": "56 13/02/2015 Golf balls - white single. Please reorder with code GB1-White",
            "UnitAmount": "5.60",
            "Quantity": 1.82
        }
    ],
    "Contact": {
        "ContactID": "ed531f74-f149-4059-b47e-6cd970189305"
    },
    "Type": "ACCREC",
    "Reference": "Job9"
}
```

*Steps to reproduce*:

1. Submit an invoice via the API using the above request. Select a customer with a Due Date and Discount configured. Note that the due date and discount fields are not specified.
2. Log into Xero and locate the newly created invoice.
3. Ensure that the new invoicing view is selected before opening the new invoice.

New Invoicing view:

1. Open the invoice in the new invoicing view.
   e.g. https://go.xero.com/app/!q8B9S/invoicing/edit/9d09075d-3a9b-4b6c-b735-e55cbaf73934
2. Observe that the invoice due date is the same as the issue date.
3. Expected this to be the 20th of the following month (e.g. 20 March 2024) as configured on the customer. And to use the organisation default if not configured on the customer.
4. Observe that the line item discount field is blank. Clicking in the field has no effect.
5. Expected the line item discount to pull through from the customer.

Classic Invoicing view:

1. Click “Switch to classic invoicing”:
   e.g. https://go.xero.com/AccountsReceivable/Edit.aspx?InvoiceID=9d09075d-3a9b-4b6c-b735-e55cbaf73934
2. Observe that the Due Date is now the 20th of the following Month.
3. Observe that the line item discount is blank but clicking in the field populates the correct value for the customer.

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't use the contact defaults but in classic invoicing there is a script that runs when you open the invoice in Xero which populates the defaults in the draft invoice if the fields are missing. This doesn't happen in new invoicing.

You would need to supply the fields. New invoicing is that it supports a discount amount or a discount rate so you can choose either.

Comment: Appreciate the response and confirmation this is a change in new invoicing.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on how Xero calculates the due dates for the various supported modes? e.g. 20th of the following month.

If we have to recreate the same logic we'll need to handle the same edge cases.

Comment: Due dates are set by the Xero user, if no contact default is set then the organisation default is used which is also set by a user. Apps would generally offer their users the option to choose what due dated they want for the invoices

Comment: Thanks for the response as per the steps to reproduce supplied - contact defaults only come through on _legacy_ invoicing which will be removed in September. So we need to know your business rules for calculating the due date so we can restore this functionality in a consistent manner for our customers on our side when they have to switch over to New Invoicing.

Comment: Apologies, my answer was unclear. You would need to ask your customers to set the due date terms in your app, Xero does not calculate the dates, the users do